# Plotly: Barplots embeded in scatterplot / network graph markers

Tags: python, matplotlib, networking, graph, plotly-dash

I am trying to visualize a Bayesian network and would like to superimpose a simple barplot showing the marginal probability distribution instead of a marker/node.

For e.g.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph([
    ('Rain', 'Grass_Wet'),
    ('Sprinkler', 'Grass_Wet'),
    ('Rain', 'Sprinkler')])

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

def generate_network_graph(G):        
    pos = nx.drawing.layout.spectral_layout(G)
    # Add additional attribute specifying node position
    label_col = 'label'
    for node in G.nodes:
        G.nodes[node]['pos'] = list(pos[node])
        G.nodes[node][label_col] = node
    # Define Figure
    traceRecode = []  # contains edge_trace, node_trace, middle_node_trace

    index = 0
    for edge in G.edges:
        x0, y0 = G.nodes[edge[0]]['pos']
        x1, y1 = G.nodes[edge[1]]['pos']
        #weight = float(G.edges[edge]['TransactionAmt']) / max(edge1['TransactionAmt']) * 10
        trace = go.Scatter(x=tuple([x0, x1, None]), y=tuple([y0, y1, None]),
                           mode='lines')
        traceRecode.append(trace)
        index = index + 1

    node_trace = go.Scatter(x=[], y=[], hovertext=[], text=[], mode='markers+text', textposition="bottom center", marker={'size': 20})

    index = 0
    for node in G.nodes():
        x, y = G.nodes[node]['pos']
        node_trace['x'] += tuple([x])
        node_trace['y'] += tuple([y])
        index = index + 1

    traceRecode.append(node_trace)

    figure = {
        "data": traceRecode,
        "layout": go.Layout(title='Bayesian Network', showlegend=False, hovermode='closest',
                            margin={'b': 40, 'l': 40, 'r': 40, 't': 40},
                            xaxis={'showgrid': False, 'zeroline': False, 'showticklabels': False},
                            yaxis={'showgrid': False, 'zeroline': False, 'showticklabels': False},
                            height=600

                            )}
    return figure

def create_bar_plot():
    figure = go.Figure(go.Bar(
            x=[0.6, 0.4],
            y=['Yes', 'No'],
            orientation='h'))

    return figure


app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Div(
            # className="six columns",
            children=[dcc.Graph(id="my-graph", figure=generate_network_graph(G))],
        ),
        html.Div(children=[dcc.Graph(id="my-graph2", figure=create_bar_plot())]),
    ]
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

would generate the first output.

[image: Now]

But I need to either embed or overlap barplots at every node showing the marginal probability distribution of that node. 
I would like to have the ability to get network orientation from networkx, as it is very important for my application. The network is quite large and it is not possible to specify barplot locations directly apriori.

[image: Desiredoutput]

Comment: Do you need this to be done with plotly? (I think I could do it with networkx and matplotlib.)

Comment: Getting this to work with plotly is not possible as illustrated in the question in my opinion. A simple hack however - that would also work in plotly - would be to just draw string labels on the nodes. And use characters to plot bars, e.g. ||||||| (0.7) vs ||| (0.3). This wouldn't be too precise but might be precise enough depending on the use case.

Comment: There are also some characters that make up good bars like these: █████████

Comment: Thanks MattL. and Philipp for your comments. I did found something in Dash - cytoscape which is an extension of cytoscape js that allows users to plot pie-charts in nodes  - I will post details in a separate answer. However, I would suggest other users looking to do the same thing to the Cytoscape GUI which allows exactly the kind of thing I was looking for - http://manual.cytoscape.org/en/stable/Styles.html please see tutorial 6: Node charts

Comment: @MehtabPathan Great answer, what do you think of adding shapes to the network figure? https://plot.ly/python/shapes/#rectangles-positioned-relative-to-the-axes This would also give you a bit more freedom in choosing what to display and where. To be fair it is not as good looking as the cytoscape and also harder to setup I guess.

Comment: @Philipp - Yes the shapes would be a viable option depending on the use case e.g. for large, complex network iterating over nodes and keeping track of of their location would be computationally prohibitive but it would work fine for smaller networks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no functionality to create node embedded bar charts in python (for an alternative - manual.cytoscape.org/en/stable/Styles.html please see tutorial 6: Node charts)- But pie charts can be created using dash-cytoscape as shown below

Adding the following block to the Cytoscape default dash style sheet will create the node with the following style

```
default_stylesheet = [{
    "selector": "node",
    "style": {
        "background-color": "green",
        "pie-size": "80%",
        "pie-1-background-color": "#E8747C",
        "pie-1-background-size": f"mapData(Yes, 0, 1, 0, 100)",
        "pie-2-background-color": "#74CBE8",
        "pie-2-background-size": f"mapData(No, 0, 1, 0, 100)",
    }]
```

[image]

Dash-cytoscape allows all majority of cytoscape js styling options given in the links which might be sufficient for your particular use case

Useful links:

https://js.cytoscape.org/demos/pie-style/
https://dash.plot.ly/cytoscape